# Is there a way to skip boot menu and go straight to windows but go to ubuntu whenever I want?

Tags: boot, startup

Now, I understand my question needs explanation. I don't know the Linux lingo quite yet. What I am asking is: Is there a way to skip the screen asking whether I want to load Windows or Ubuntu, and load Windows every time. I also want the option to be able to load into Ubuntu on startup if I so choose. But, otherwise I want to load Windows every time without being stopped by the screen asking which OS I want.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using GRUB.

If yes, edit the `/etc/default/grub` the following: (edit, not add)

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0    #replace 0 by order of Windows in grub menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

After running `sudo update-grub`, GRUB should only show up if you hit a specific key (depending on GRUB version, it's <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.)

Comment: Please accept if working

Comment: I just need to get it on my computer, This was the reason I got rid of it last time I just wanted to make sure there was a way before I put it back on I will accept within the next 24 hours if it works

Comment: Is it working? If yes, please accept.